# how to create a simics project with targets/qsp-x86 from CLI (project-setup)?

Tags: simics

If I use the GUI to create a simics project, I can click an all the addons (OSS-Sources, QSP-x86, and so on) and the project's `targets` dir will contain these subdirs:

```
cosim qsp-x86 simics-builder-training simics-user-training vacuum workshop-01
```

If I run

```
$HOME/simics/simics-6.0.89/bin/project-setup simics-test2
```

the `targets` directory only contains

```
cosim  vacuum
```

What flags do I need to pass to `project-setup` in order to install all addons?

Also, where can I get such information other than on stack overflow?
I tried reading `project-setup -h` and tried some of the flags there (e.g. `--package-list $HOME/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44`), but nothing worked.

Comment: The root cause is that the ispm does not automatically set up a .package-list in your Simics base package. Instead, it is based on the idea that you should configure each project with a local .package-list. And that in turn can be created using the manifest that is part of the public Simics installation bundle.  The core reasoning is that in the general case you might have several different versions of targets using the same base package, just not all at once.

Comment: You can use the ISPM GUI and the addons view to set up the .package-list in the base package installation.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `addon-manager` in your project to create its own package-list.

```
cd simics-test2
./bin/addon-manager -C -s ~/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44
```

Comment: you can also use multiple -s PATH, such as ./bin/addon-manager -C -s ~/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44 -s ~/simics/simics-training-6.0.pre13

Comment: Thank you! 
`./bin/addon-manager -C -s ~/simics/simics-qsp-x86-6.0.44 -s  ~/simics/simics-qsp-clear-linux-6.0.9` has the desired effect - I can now run `./simics -no-gui  targets/qsp-x86/firststeps-no-network.simics`

Comment: You can also use the ISPM in GUI mode to click on the packages you want for your project. Or you can use it from the command-line, but that is actually less convenient than using addon-manager except if you have a manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Having a `.packagelist` file in the installation of Simics Base would make all packages in that list ***global*** for that version of Simics Base. Which is not always what you want.

Having project-local `.packagelist` files gives you the neat option to select exactly which add-on packages you want with a particular version of Simics Base.

ISPM handle all of this for you quite seamlessly. But as Jakob mentioned, it does not add any "global" `.packagelist` file to the work flow.